# What's wrong with my Gems? Terminal doesn't reconize them

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I execute for instance:

```
gem list
```

and I get this:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.2.1, 3.1.3, 3.1.1, 3.0.5)
actionpack (3.2.1, 3.1.3, 3.1.1, 3.0.5)
activemodel (3.2.1, 3.1.3, 3.1.1, 3.0.5)
(...)
uglifier (1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.1.0, 1.0.3)
webrat (0.7.3)
xpath (0.1.4)
```

Them if I try with

```
irb --simple-prompt
>> require 'webrat'
```

I get

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- webrat
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

And this happens with every Gem on the list. What's wrong? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. Sorry if this is dumb, but I got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require rubygems before you can require any gems. You can do this in irb:

```
$ irb --simple-prompt
>> require 'rubygems'
>> require 'webrat'
```

or when starting irb up:

```
$ irb --simple-prompt -r rubygems
>> require 'webrat'
```

Comment: BTW: there's a file called `ubygems.rb` as well, which just has the line `require 'rubygems'` in it. That way, you can say `-rubygems` instead of `-rrubygems`. Ah, the length to which Ruby developers go to make their libraries nice to use :-)

Comment: Yeah, I laughed when I found out that you could require ubygems!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.9 package now includes RubyGems by **default** on most platforms.This means that on Ruby 1.9 and above, you will not need to `require 'rubygems'` in order to load gem libraries.

if you use like this: `require 'rubygems'`

The **big problem** with this approach is that you don’t want to make this change to every single Ruby program you download!

While ok for quick scripts you write yourself, this is not the way to **go.**

Comment: yeah, you're right. I'm still using 1.87, I have to switch to 1.9x as soon as possible. Thanks ;